# What did Kim Wexler mean when she said her bar license "does not have an expiration date"?

Tags: plot-explanation, better-call-saul

In the series finale of *Better Call Saul*, Kim visits Saul in prison as his lawyer. Saul is surprised and asks Kim how she managed to get her bar license back. She replies:

> It turns out my bar license does not have an expiration date.

This is very confusing to me, as Kim voluntarily gave up her license as a lawyer after Howard's death. Voluntary termination has nothing to do with her bar license's expiration date.

I am wondering if it is a joke or if, in the state of New Mexico, even with voluntary termination, a bar license does not expire.

Any ideas?

Comment: Kim doesn't visit Saul. She visits Jimmy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Kim's line was:

> Uh, turns out my New Mexico bar card doesn't have an expiration date.

I interpreted that as Kim still has possession of her ID card as a licensed lawyer and that said card doesn't have an expiration date printed on it. Because her ID didn't have an expiration date on it, when the prison officers saw her ID, they thought that she was still a licensed lawyer and allowed her in the prison. Basically, she scammed her way in, like the good ol' days with Jimmy / Saul.

Comment: right, right, it has to be this way. It aligns with their character arc.

Comment: In at least some states, you have to turn in your id if you get disbarred, but I don't know about NM. Also, I guess she wasn't really disbarred, she withdrew from the bar.

Comment: Interesting and maybe correct interpretation. But how could she keep her lawyer card after she gives up the bar? Isn't that the first thing the bar wants to get when a lawyer "gives up"?